# Cannot increment a number in swift

Tags: swift

I have a variable populated from a keystore, that when incremented, gives an error that reads: 
**"NSNumber is not convertible to @lvalue UIint8"**

```
if let bankbalance: AnyObject? = keystore.objectForKey("coinbalance"){
   let mybalance = bankbalance as NSNumber
    mybalance += 50 //this line gives the error 
}
```

My question is what is convertible to UIint8 so that I can add to my variable? I've tried INT, Float, double.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are trying to add a value to a `let` and let is a constant, you can not assign values to a `let` after you initialized it.

Apple docs:

> Constants and variables associate a name (such as maximumNumberOfLoginAttempts or welcomeMessage) with a value of a particular type (such as the number 10 or the string "Hello"). The value of a constant cannot be changed once it is set, whereas a variable can be set to a different value in the future.

```
var
```

is what you want

Answer (score 5):

Use var. Because let means constants.

```
var mybalance = bankbalance as NSNumber
```

But NSNumber is a Object and mybalance.integerValue cannot be assigned.

```
if let bankbalance: AnyObject? = keystore.objectForKey("coinbalance"){
    let mybalance: NSNumber = bankbalance as NSNumber
    var b = mybalance.integerValue + 50;
}
```

Comment: That's silly of me. I know better. however, that gives me an error that reads NSNumber is not identical to UInt8. But I cannot cast bankbalance as UInt8

Comment: I solved this if anyone is curious. You have to downcast to Int before you can downcast UInt8

Comment: sorry! I fixed my code. please reload your browser.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot increment constants.`let` is keyword in swift for constants which means after defining its value you cannot alter it.
`var` is another keyword which means variable and you can alter the value which declared with var keyword.

```
if let bankbalance: AnyObject? = keystore.objectForKey("coinbalance"){

    //use var instead of let
    var mybalance = bankbalance as NSNumber
    mybalance = mybalance.integerValue + 50  //use integervalue as we cast to `NSNumber`
}
```

this will works

Comment: But aren't we altering bankbalance by casting it as an NSNumber after we've defined it as a constant with let? This triggers an error: " NSNumber is not identical to UInt8"

Comment: edited my answer.We need to get integerValue of `NSNumber` as we are casting it `NSNumber`